# how to manage two EDMX files incase they have the same table name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application,. i use the entity framework A`DO.net entity data module` to map two different databases and i have created two `EDMX` files. but unfortunately these databases have two tables with the same name UserGroup & Router. so i am unable to map these two tables inside the EDMX files, as entity framework will automatically delete the existing table which have the same name.

can any one advice how i can fix this , without having to rename the tables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may change the name of the table on designer. Click the entity on designer and click and change the name property. Or you may have these two edmx in different name spaces (If it is possible)

Answer (score 0):

Each EDMX file will have some namespace :

```
using DB1DBModel;

using DB2DBModel;



Class MyClass
{
void SomeMethod()
{

// table with same name MyTable in first edmx
DB1DBModel.EntitiesXYZ.MyTable=new DB1DBModel.EntitiesXYZ.MyTable(); 
// tables with same name MyTable in second edmx
DB2DBMode2.EntitiesABC.MyTable=new DB2DBMode2.EntitiesABC.MyTable();




}

}
```

// Hope this works